# How to log in to turn off Num Lock on a MacBook Pro when you can't login?

Tags: macbook-pro, login

How do I turn off Num Lock on my MacBook Pro when I can't log in to get to System Preferences?

Comment: Try hitting a button labeled `CLEAR`.

Comment: I am assuming that you mean you can't login because Num Lock is enabled and you can't enter your password because the wrong keys are being sent. Correct?  If this is the case, please add that to your question for clarity.

Comment: @John Ramos, There is no "button labeled `CLEAR`" on a MacBook Pro.

Comment: @diane wilkinson, What model MacBook Pro do you have and what version of OS X are you running? Are you using an external Keyboard, if so what type and if not do you have a USB Full Keyboard you can temporarily use to get past the Num Lock issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling mouse keys. System Preferences > Accessibility > Mouse & Trackpad > Uncheck mouse keys if it is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else has this problem, try pressing the Fn key and the down arrow at the same time.